# read csv from SharePoint with Pandas (Python authentication code)

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint

I have a csv in the documents section of a SharePoint site. I would like to import it in Pandas. Of course is I use just the normal code below I get HTTP error 403 Forbidden.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('link from sharepoint')
```

How do I get SharePoint authentication to work using Python so Pandas can read the csv file.

I have already searched and tried code in several internet posts, but either the code is too generic that I do not know what it means 
e.g.

```
username = 'YourDomain\\account'
```

or

```
user = r'SERVER\user'
```

or it just didn't.

Is there a simple way to get authentication to work and import the file in Pandas?

Comment: I have a link from sharepoint and my username and password.

Comment: have you tried the pypi package [sharepoint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sharepoint)?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know how to use it. Lost in the part "site_url = server_url + "sites/foo/bar"". Is the server_url the sharepoint link of the document or something else (this is not a list, it's a csv document). And what is this string supposed to be "sites/foo/bar"? No clue. I'm talking about the USAGE code from the page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sharepoint

Comment: Well, I have never used a sharepoint but I guess you have a url like "sharepoint.myurl.com" and from there you have "/url_path/to/mycsv.csv", so in the example they merge them to be "sharepoint.myurl.com/url_path/to/mycsv.csv". Another approach would be to use `requests` package and create a session. Do you have test user & password to include in your question I could help further.

Answer (score 5):

Relatively easy solution with sharepy:

```
import io
import sharepy
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://yoursharepointsite.sharepoint.com'
FILE_URL = '/sites/...path to your file.../yourfilename.csv'
SHAREPOINT_USER = 'yourusername'
SHAREPOINT_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'

s = sharepy.connect(URL, username=SHAREPOINT_USER, password=SHAREPOINT_PASSWORD).
r = s.get(URL+FILE_URL)
f = io.BytesIO(r.content)
df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: what do SHAREPOINT_USER and SHAREPOINT_PASSWORD mean here same as 'yourusername' and 'yourpassword'

Comment: Tried your code, but I get `Requesting security token...Could not connect to login.microsoftonline.com` at the `sharepy.connect` command, which is strange, since I am trying to connect to a *corporate* SP server, not one from M$!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your SP username and password are identical to your Windows login credentials, which is very common, the following should work (mostly [taken from here](https://github.com/brandond/requests-negotiate-sspi)):

```
import requests
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://yoursharepointsite.sharepoint.com'
fileUrl = '/sites/...path to your file.../yourfilename.csv'

r = requests.get(url + fileUrl, auth=HttpNegotiateAuth())
df = pd.read_csv(r.text)
```

I tested it with `read_excel(r.content)`, since I had an XLSX file instead of a CSV. It seems that XLSX files are treated as binaries. But with CSV being parsed as text, it should work as posted. Feel free to report back.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can't, but what you can do is use an API to connect python to SharePoint.

What I do is use SharePlum -> download via pip 
(pip install shareplum)

```
import sys, pandas, datetime
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from shareplum import Site

auth = HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN' + '\\' + str(username), str(password)) 
site = Site('sharepointsiteurl', auth=auth, verify_ssl=True) # set to False if behind firewall

site_list = site.List('Name of List')

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(site_list)

# then do what you need to in Pandas
```

Edit:
Since you are trying to download a CSV file. use the python-sharepoint api

same thing as above but instead of the

```
site_list = site.List('Name of List')
# do instead
site.download('nameoffile.csv', 'D:/location/to/save.csv')
```

Comment: Since you are trying to download a CSV file, try something like this...

Comment: Nor shareplum or python-sharepoint have any method like site.download()

Answer (score 0):

Below is a complete code for file/folder management in ShaprePoint which allows you to read, write, and delete files. In the example, I'm reading excel file into pandas dataframe.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from shareplum import Site, Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

config = {'user': {email},
          'password': {password},
          'base_url': 'https://{domain}.sharepoint.com',
          'site': 'https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}/',
          'doc_library': 'Shared Documents/{folder}'
          }


def authenticate():
    auth = Office365(config['base_url'], username=config['user'], password=config['password']).GetCookies()
    site = Site(config['site'], version=Version.v365, authcookie=auth)
    return site


def connect_folder(sharepoint_folder):
    site = authenticate()
    sharepoint_dir = '/'.join([config['doc_library'], sharepoint_folder])
    folder = site.Folder(sharepoint_dir)
    return folder


def upload_file(local_file, sharepoint_folder):
    file_name = os.path.basename(local_file)
    folder = connect_folder(sharepoint_folder)
    with open(local_file, mode='rb') as file_obj:
        file_content = file_obj.read()

    folder.upload_file(file_content, file_name)


def read_file(file_name, sharepoint_folder):
    folder = connect_folder(sharepoint_folder)
    df = pd.read_excel(folder.get_file(file_name))
    return df


def delete_file(file_name, sharepoint_folder):
    folder = connect_folder(sharepoint_folder)
    folder.delete_file(file_name)


sharepoint_folder = 'Test'
local_file = '/file/path/location/excel_file_test.xlsx'
file_name = os.path.basename(local_file)
upload_file(local_file, sharepoint_folder)
df = read_file(file_name, sharepoint_folder)
print(df)
```